# MongoDB and Mongoose: an issue with ES6 syntax in $where callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am working on Node.JS (6.6.0) application which uses MongoDB(3.2.10) as database and Mongoose (1.4.X) library. 
Code below should execute a query on MongoDB database:

```
const JobStat = require('../models/job_stat')
const co = require('co')

let statService = {
  getRecentJobsStat () {
    return co(function* () {
      // Another async code

      let result = yield JobStat
      .$where(function () {
        let condition = true
        // I omit full condition since it does not matter here
        return condition
      })
      .sort({
        value: 1
      })
      .exec()
      return result
    })
  }
}

module.exports = statService
```

Unfortunately it does not work and generates this exception:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @:2:12
```

When i changed variable definition inside $where callback function from let to var (var condition = true), this query had executed successfully. I use 6.6.0 version of Node.js and another ES6 features work fine for me.
So the question is: what is the reason of this error? Does the problem exist in my code or in MongoDB/Mongoose? Thanks for any help.

**UPD:** 
I ran this query in mongo shell and had got exactly same result:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its `let` causing it?

Comment: Functions passed to `$where` run inside the MongoDB server, which—since you're using 3.2— _should_ support [most of ES6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-javascript/#modernized-javascript-implementation-es6).

Comment: @JackTuck, i updated my question, you can see how it works in mongo shell for me

Comment: Interesting. So i gave it a go in mongo shell and can reproduce. But if you use `const` rather than `let` it works. So i don't think its anything to do with ES6. Could it be mongo throwing a fit because `let` in this context is `$let`?

Comment: @JackTuck, i agree with you. I tried arrow function inside `$where` callback and it works, so this bug should be related only with `let` keywork

Comment: For those still having an issue with this, or searching for this, MongoDB doesn't allow "let" declarations, but does allow "const", most weirdly. I had to resort to using "var".